# Print table cells side-by-side with survey responses

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm getting survey responses. I'm trying to list these answers by making a table.
Every 4 records represent 4 answers on 4 questions. The goal is to print them side-by-side in one row.

Data from DB:

```
id      user_id     question_id     gsm     answer          date

1       1           1               xxxx    3               2021.08.08
2       1           2               xxxx    2               2021.08.08
3       1           3               xxxx    1               2021.08.08
4       1           4               xxxx    comment         2021.08.08

5       1           1               xxxx    3               2021.08.08
6       1           2               xxxx    2               2021.08.08
7       1           3               xxxx    1               2021.08.08
8       1           4               xxxx    comment         2021.08.08
```

```
<table style="width: 100%;" id="example2" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>user</th>
            <th>Question1</th>
            <th>Question2</th>
            <th>Question3</th>
            <th>Question4(Comment)</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                 
        <?php 
        $sql=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."' ");
        foreach($sql as $rows){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php  echo $sql['user_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $sql['answer'];  ?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $sql['answer'];  ?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $sql['answer'];  ?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $sql['answer'];  ?></td>
            <td><?php  echo $sql['date']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How could I print all 4 records (answers) side-by-side in one `tr` for users from DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the many ways to get the desired result:

```
<tbody>                                 
    <?php 
    $sql=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."' ");

    $quest = array_unique(array_column($sql, 'question_id'));
    sort($quest); // optional

    $data = [];
    foreach ($sql as $row) {

        $user_id = $row['user_id'];

        if (!isset($data[$user_id])) {
            $data[$user_id] = ['date' => $row['date'], 'ans' => []];
        }

        foreach ($quest as $question_id) {
            if ($row['question_id'] == $question_id) {
                $data[$user_id]['ans'][$question_id] = $row['answer'];
            }
        }
    } 

    foreach($data as $userID => $user_data){
    ?>
    <tr> 
        <td> User ID: <?= $userID ?></td>
        <?php foreach($user_data['ans'] as $q_id => $q_ans){ ?>
        <td><?= $q_ans ?></td> 
        <?php } ?>
        <td> Date: <?= $user_data['date'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

And here is a [**demo.**](https://3v4l.org/Chs3N)